# Accessing class in usercontrol page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class `a.cs` in which I have a method `save()` and I have a user control `b.ascx` and I want to bind a `GridView` by using save method. Something like that

```
gridview1.datasource = //want to call save method here
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind a method to a property you can do like this:

Add this to your resources

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="aName" MethodName="Save"      //Save is the name of your method
                    ObjectType="{x:Type Namespace:a}" /> //a is the class name
```

Then you can simply bind it to your `DataSource`. e.g:

```
DataSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource aName}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a aliasOfClass = new a(); // if your class has constructor defined
```

now use

```
gridview1.datasource = aliasOfClass.save();
```

And if your class does not have constructor defined then make the method static and use like this

```
gridview1.datasource = a.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First ensure that your method & your class modifier is `public`.
2. Ensure you have `using` the `namespace` on your `UserControl` class (If your class is located on another project/ class library)

In this example my class and UserControl located on same the project.

[image: Web Application Project Structure Sample]

I assume your class is like this:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public object Save()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

On your User Control just like this:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyClass obj = new MyClass();
            myGridView.DataSource = obj.Save();
            myGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```